# Problema con evaluación de un 'map' con Jinja

Tags: python

Estoy intentando armar un mapa con defaults para un rol de Ansible/Jinja2, que puede llegar a popularse desde otro mapa externo.

De no encontrarse el mapa externo, se setean defaults para cada item necesario del mapa.

Inicialmente seria algo por el estilo:

```
ctxProp:
  mail:
    relay:
      host: "{{ mail.server.host | default('smtp-relay.gmail.com') }}"
      port: "{{ mail.server.port | default('587') }}"
      tls:  "{{ mail.server.tls  | default('true') }}"
      auth: "{{ mail.server.auth | default('false') }}"
      user: "{{ mail.server.user | default('user') }}"
      pass: "{{ mail.server.pass | default('pass') }}"
```

El problema que estoy teniendo, es que al momento de evaluar si existe o no, por ejemplo, "mail.server.host", me surge una falla indicando que 'mail' no se encuentra definido.

```
failed: [<host>] <...> u'relay': {u'tls': u\"{{ mail.server.tls  | default('true') }}\", u'auth': u\"{{ mail.server.auth | default('false') }}\", u'host': u\"{{ mail.server.host | default('smtp-relay.gmail.com') }}\", u'user': u\"{{ mail.server.user | default('') }}\", u'pass': u\"{{ mail.server.pass | default('') }}\", u'port': u\"{{ mail.server.port | default('587') }}\"}}}: 'mail' is undefined"}
```

Osea, en lugar de evaluar toda la rama del mapa "mail -> relay -> host" al momento de ver si esta declarada o no, solamente evalúa 'host', esperando que los dos niveles superiores (relay y mail) si estén definidos.

Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo.

y Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente parece el filtro default de Jinja2 da error si alguno de los niveles superiores no está definido.

Como apaño (aka *workaround*) se puede definir la variable previamente si no está definida:

```
- name: Set default mail config container varaible
  set_fact:
     mail:
  when: mail is undefined

- name: Set default server config
  set_fact:
     mail:
       server:
         host: smtp-relay.gmail.com
         port: 587
         tls:  true
         auth: false
         user: user
         pass: pass
  when: mail.server is undefined
```

Comment: Gracias @sanzante, el tema con ese workaround, es que puedo llegar a tener multiples niveles a crear casi dinamicamente en un template, por lo que tendria que codear algun tipo de funcion que creara todos los "padres". 

u_U

Comment: Puedes usar un loop con set_fact para generar los padres, incluso recibiendo una lista dinámica si no recuerdo mal. El caso es que el filtro *default* no parece que haga eso ni parece que se le vaya añadir esa funcionalidad.